# Web folder options: are all webdav servers created equal?

Tags: windows, webdav, web-folders

I have implemented a webdav using PHP on Apache. However, I'm having some issues when testing it with XP web folders.

I notice that when I right-click on any folder, the 'new' option only contains an option for 'folder' i.e., I can only create new folders and not files. Also, when I right-click on a file, I can only see an option for 'open', which presumably will open the file using its associated program. The 'Open With' option is not available. Furthermore, even opening the file usually brings up my browser trying to open it, and not the associated program. Finally, even when I get a program like MS Word to open a file, I am unable to save it in-place.

I believe web folders on windows supports all these features, just like windows explorer. Interestingly, when I access the test webdav server at [www.ajaxfilebrowser.com](http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com) with web folders, I get all these features, which leads me to suspect the issue involves my implementation of webdav. However, if all required webdav methods have been implemented, what differentiates one webdav server from another? Are there some properties that web folders uses to determine what options to enable?

Comment: If all else fails, you could throw [wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) on the machine and try to read the differences in interactions between your server and the test server you've found (or a Subversion running with WebDAV support).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I now have wireshark installed. It's a bit challenging to interpret and compare the traces (even with HTTP decoding), but it helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

Things to look for:

- OPTIONS response "Allow" and "Dav" headers
- support for LOCK (may be required for writing)
- media types

In doubt, capture HTTP traces and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your LOCK management. Required by most clients or they will operate in "read only" mode.

Comment: This may be true, but I am able to write to the server. The problem is with the options enabled on the folder. I notice that windows sees the ajaxfilebrowser server as a network  share, whilst regular webdav folders are seen as web folders. The issue is then how to coax Windows into seeing my webdav server as a network share.